# How to use on conflict update to just replace the row?

Tags: postgresql

Having a DB with columns:  `date_num, name, c, o, v`, where `date_num, name,` are unique.

When insert, if the `date_num`, and `name` columns combination already exist, I want to **replace** the **whole** row as is.

```
df.to_sql('temp_insert', connection, if_exists ='replace')
sql = (
        '''INSERT INTO {table_name} ({cols}) 
        SELECT {cols} FROM temp_insert 
        ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE'''.format(table_name=table_name,cols=cols)
    )
```

after `DO UPDATE`, what do I have to `SET` to just replace that row ?

```
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET .... ?
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `EXCLUDE` clause to do some computes, for example:

```
DO UPDATE SET your_column = EXCLUDED.your_column;
```

from the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

> Note that the special excluded table is used to reference values originally proposed for insertion:

Comment: sorry I did not understand you, how in this specific case I simply keep inserting what I was trying to insert in this code.

Comment: He said that in sql variable you must have `INSERT INTO {table_name} ({cols}) SELECT {cols} FROM temp_insert ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE set col1 = excluded.col1, col2 = excluded.col2,..., coln = excluded.coln`. It's up to you to format your sql as it should be

Comment: ii do not have access to column in this specific moment, as you see I copy a full table into another table, how should I know what column is to be updated?

Comment: what your_column means ? I am copying one table to another, then it stops on some row which already exists, how do I access that row, and update it?

Comment: you must read the [doc and examples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) to understand ;-)

Comment: I did read it, twice, and there is no answer to my question, they explicitly insert columns names,  and then use col=excluded.col , and this was your answer, but my question is about the case when one insert columns as {col}, then I can't do {col}=excluded.{col} , so you didn't answer the question.